# Using foreach loop to creat anew variable in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have 1 000 000 observations and I need to run a for loop with some condition to create a new variable (Test) in my dataset (T1). As my dataset is very large, the execution is very long. So I try to use `foreach` to optimize time.
here is what I'm trying to do, but it is not work well. Any suggestion please?

This is an example of my input:

```
T1 <- read.table(text="
ID CodeActe   Cout test
1  1      356  34.00   NA
2  1      357   8.00   NA
3  1      363   5.75   NA
4  1     9411 150.00   NA
5  2     9411 150.00   NA
6  2      363   5.75   NA", header=T)
```

and my code:

```
res <- foreach::foreach(i=1:nrow(T1),.combine = rbind)  %dopar% {
if (i+1 > nrow(T1)){
  break
}
if (T1$ID[i]==T1$ID[i+1]){

  if (T1$CodeActe[i]==356){
    T1$test[i]<-1
  }
  else if (T1$CodeActe[i]==357){
    T1$test[i]<-0
  }
  else if (T1$CodeActe[i]==363){
    T1$test[i]<-0
  }
  else{
    T1$test[i]<-T1$CodeActe[i]
  }
}}
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Please see my input below

Comment: So what's the deisred output for this input? What happens when `T1$ID[i] != T1$ID[i+1]`? Do you want to keep the NA?

Comment: when T1$ID[i] != T1$ID[i+1] applicate this code: if (T1$ID[i]!=T1$ID[i+1]){
  if (T1$CodeActe[i]==363){
    T1$test[i]<-0
  }
  else{
    T1$test[i]<-T1$CodeActe[i]
  } 
}}

Comment: You should have a look at `dplyr` (see https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dplyr.html). In particular, functions `group_by(...)`, `mutate(...)` and `case_when(...)` will be helpful. It is not parallelized but in my experience, this is not a problem for simple operations up to at least 100M records, running on a laptop.